# Assigning value to a string inside onResponse method Volley

Tags: json, android-volley

Okey, I'm trying to get a Json response and return it as string using Volley. I have a method called `getWeatherData` which returns String which is the JsonObject comes from JSONObjectRequest response. In that method I'm creating a JsonObjectRequest called`request` with the url of my API which returns a JSON Object in response.

Now I want to take that JSON object inside the `onResponse` method but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I tried to creat a string in my`getWeatherData` function and the inside the `onResponse` method just assign that value to returning JSONObject but I get syntax error *'variable accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final'*.

```
public String getWeatherData(String place){

    String getJsonData;
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Utils.BASE_URL1 + place + Utils.BASE_URL2, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            getJsonData = response.toString();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("json_retrieving-problem",error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

All I want is to retrive the `JSONObject response` from the `onResponse` method and then return that value as string.

Comment: _All I want is to retrive the JSONObject response from the onResponse_ to where?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the same class,

You can **define** a function, `returnMyString()` like,

```
private void returnMyString(String myString) {
        //do your stuff 
}
```

Then in `JsonRequest`,

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Utils.BASE_URL1 + place + Utils.BASE_URL2, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //call the function defined to return string
            returnMyString(response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("json_retrieving-problem",error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Or If you want a **callback**, define an interface and call the method in Interface like [this](http://mobikul.com/how-to-send-json-post-request-using-volley-rest-api/)

Comment: that doesn't work. I think I couldn't explain what I want to do but I been looking around and I actually found the solution from this link [http://mobikul.com/how-to-send-json-post-request-using-volley-rest-api/](http://mobikul.com/how-to-send-json-post-request-using-volley-rest-api/). I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @AhmetUrun Glad you got the answer.